# How to get value from Map key in java

Tags: java, string, amazon-web-services, dictionary, key

I am trying to receive message attributes from Amazon SQS with the following code :

```
Map<String, com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.MessageAttributeValue> attributes = new HashMap<String, com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.MessageAttributeValue>();
attributes = message.getMessageAttributes();
for(String key: attributes.keySet()){
    System.out.println(key + " - "+ attributes.get(key));
}
```

and it returns the output:

```
project - {StringValue: 25,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],DataType: String}
```

I want to get only the value 25. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
attributes.get("project").getStringValue()
```

References:

- [How to extract from a Map the value of a given key?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object))
- [How to extract a String Value of a given MessageAttributeValue?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/MessageAttributeValue.html#getStringValue())

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the object of value type `com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.MessageAttributeValue` declared in your `Map` .

You need to get the value out of that object like the way you would normally do :

```
for(String key: attributes.keySet()){
   com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.MessageAttributeValue object =  attributes.get(key);
   //some method to get that 25 value
   System.out.println(key + " - "+ object.getStringValue());

}
```

Comment: Juste to complete : the method is  object.getStringValue() : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/MessageAttributeValue.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop on your map here is an example to show you how to get the values of the map: 
I have a : `Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

```
 for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                     System.out.println("entry key : "+entry.getKey());
                     System.out.println("Object value :"+entry.getValue());
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this (library org.json.JSONObject; [java-json.jar])

```js
Map<String, com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.MessageAttributeValue> attributes = new HashMap<String, com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.MessageAttributeValue>();
        attributes = message.getMessageAttributes();
        for(String key: attributes.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " - "+ attributes.get(key));
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(attributes.get(key));
                System.out.println(json.get("StringValue"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```